# Chi Square Test using Frequencies, Bins, CDF, Python

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying to write a chi square goodness-of-fit test for Beta distribution from scratch, without using any external functions. The code below reports '1' for a fit, even though kstest from scipy.stats returns a zero. Data is distributed normally, so my function should also return zero.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2
from scipy.stats import beta
from scipy.stats import kstest
from scipy.stats import norm

preds = norm.rvs(5,2,size=200)
preds.sort()

bin_size = 30
bins = np.linspace(0,10,bin_size)
counts = np.digitize(preds, bins)
mean = 5
var = 2

sum = 0
for i in range(len(bins)-1):
    p = beta.cdf(bins[i+1], mean, var) - beta.cdf(bins[i], mean, var)  
    freq = len(counts[counts==i]) / float(len(counts))    
    sum = sum + ((freq - p)**2)/p

dof = len(counts)-2
pval = 1 - chi2.cdf(sum, dof)
print pval
```

In the code, I create bins, measure frequencies based on the bins, calculate expected frequency using Beta distribution CDF, and sum it up resulting in the X^2 test statistic.

The kstest call is

```
print kstest(preds, 'beta', [mean, var])
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: Output is '1' for my function and (0.97653486524680988, 0.0) for the kstest call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the DOF definition:

dof = len(preds)-2

is the correct choice. Also, I had to reduce bin size to 15 in order to get consistent '0' result. It is known that Chi^2 tests are sensitive on bin size.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your answer to your own question is correct, and there are a series of problems in your codes.

Firstly, according to your implementation, the dof calculated using `len(counts)-2` is the same thing as `len(preds)-2`. So changing that doesn't make any difference.

Secondly, to do a Chi^2 test on the parameter fit, you need to construct a number of bins that are MECE, which means no overlapping between bins and they collectively span all possible values of `X`. However, by setting up your bins using `bins = np.linspace(0,10,bin_size)`, you forced the rightmost bin to stop at `10`. While the Gaussian distribution spans -inf to inf. So there is chance that the random numbers you generated shoot over `10`.

But that might be less of a problem in comparison with this one: the number of counts for each bin is conventionally required to be 5 at least. However, using your method to count the numbers falling into the bins (here you set to 30 bins) could and actually almost always have numbers below 5, and even 0. 0 counts in any bin leads to infinity in the subsequent `sum` calculation, and that could give a rejection no matter the fit is good or bad. And I think that's why you get a 0 after changing the dof to be `len(preds)-2`, you just happen to have at least one 0 in the bin counts.

Another problem is the calculation of Chi^2. I think you don't use frequencies, but actual counts in each bin:

```
p = beta.cdf(bins[i+1], mean, var) - beta.cdf(bins[i], mean, var)  
p = p*200
freq = len(counts[counts==i])    
sum = sum + ((freq - p)**2)/p
```

So both `p` and `freq` are the number of counts in each category, rather than relative frequencies. But I am not entirely sure about this.

Finally, the definition of dof is number of bins - number of parameters fit (here 2) -1.
So if you have 10 bins, `dof = 10 - 2 - 1 = 7`. In your code this is `200 - 2 = 198'. A chi^2 distribution with such a big dof is extremely flattened, which means you need extremely large chi^2 value to reject the fit. That's the reason you get 1 using your code.